# Command in package.json for setup environment

Tags: node.js, webpack, angular7

Using Angular 7, I need the command which I can hit in command line/terminal like yarn serve --SERVER_API_URL = 'https://localhost:8000', 
but I don't need to write the hard coded values to SERVER_API_URL in my code.

I tried to write the command in package.json
"serve:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && yarn run webpack:dev-run" but still I am getting the localhost server instead of dev server like "dev.hello.net". and similar for test environment and production.

```
export const SERVER_API_URL = process.env.SERVER_API_URL;
```

```
"serve:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && yarn run webpack:dev-run",
```

```
 plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: `'${options.env}'`,
                DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'development',
                SERVER_API_URL: `''`
            }
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(utils.root('../public/app'), {root: utils.root(), verbose: true}),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: './src/assets',
                to: 'assets',
                ignore: ['images/**/*', 'fonts/**/*']
            },
        ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make changes in your webpack.config.js file for accepting env values. for that find plugins section and make modifications like following.

webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                // "process": undefined,
                'process.env': {
                    'buildmode': JSON.stringify(env && env.buildmode ? env.buildmode : "")                   
                    // etc, these are just examples
                }
            })
]
```

so while running your application use following parameters with ng command

```
--env.buildmode='Production'
```

fetch env variables in your angular applications.

```
declare var process: any;
export class test{
constructor(){
 console.log('env variables', this.getEnvironmentVars('buildmode'));
}

private getEnvironmentVars(key: string): string {
    console.log('process', process);
    if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process && process.env) {
      return process.env[key];
    } else {
      return BuildMode.DEVELOPMENT
    }
  }

}
```